# Prolog Eliza implementation - Loops and Recursion

Tags: loops, recursion, prolog

can someone explain to me why this code won't work right? It is stuck in a loop of saying false. I am not quite sure how to run it that may be the issue. I want it to look something like this

```
Ready> [you,are,a,computer].
Eliza: i am not a computer
Ready> [do,you,speak,portuguese].
Eliza: no, i speak russian
Ready>
```

```
change(X,Y):- X = 'you', Y = 'i'.
change(X,Y):- X = 'i', Y = 'why do you'.
change(X,Y):- X = 'are', Y = 'am not'.
change(X,Y):- X = 'do', Y = 'no'.
change(X,Y):- X = 'portuguese', Y = 'russian'.


eliza :-
    write('Hello! My name is eliza.'), nl,
    eliza_loop.

eliza_loop :-
    write('Eliza > '),
    read(Input), respond(Input).

respond(Input) :-
    member(Term, Input),
    member(Term, [ quit, exit, leave ]),
    write('Goodbye!').

respond([my,name,is,Name | _ ]) :-
    write('Hello, '), write(Name), write('! Pleased to meet you.'), nl,
    eliza_loop.

respond([my,Thing,is,called,Name | _ ]) :-
    write(Name), write(' is a nice name for a '), write(Thing), write('.'), nl,
    eliza_loop.
respond(Input) :-
    member(Animal, Input),
    member(Animal, [ cat, dog, fish, hamster, gerbil, snake, tortoise ]),
    write('You just mentioned your '), write(Animal), write('. Tell me more about your '), write(Animal), nl,
    eliza_loop.

respond(Input) :-
    member(Term, Input),
    member(Term, [ hate, dislike ]),
    member(Term2, Input),
    member(Term2, [ you ]),
    write(':('), nl,
    eliza_loop.

respond([ _ ]) :-
    retract(list_of_excuses([ Next | Rest ])),
    append(Rest, [ Next ], NewExcuseList),
    asserta(list_of_excuses(NewExcuseList)),
    write(Next), nl,
    eliza_loop.
```

Answer (score 1):

I does work.

If you enter `[dog].` for example (with the dot!):

Load eliza in file `eliza.pl`:

```
?- [eliza].
true.
```

Run it, then enter `[dog].` (a list, followed by a dot. Note that SWI-Prolog doesn't take kindly to the final `]` and issues a CR for some reason):

```
?- eliza.
Hello! My name is eliza.
[dog].> [dog
You just mentioned your dog. Tell me more about your dog
Eliza > |:
```

Still, `read(Input)` is a problem because it is supposed to read a "term" (i.e. serialized output).

If you have [read_line_to_string/2](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=read_line_to_string/2) in your Prolog, use that, followed by something like [atom_split/3](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=ifprolog%3Aatom_split/3) to break the string at the blanks.

Also use [format/2](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=format/2) for printing.